# Django Model Formset very slow on POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to allow users to modify multiple records in one screen, so Django Formsets seemed to be the best bet.  Each form in the formset contains 9 foreign key fields which leads to running many many queries.  I solved this on form rendering side by using Jquery Autocomplete for each of these, this reduced the render time from 30 or 40 seconds down to about 3 or 4 (reduced hundreds of queries down to 4).  The performance problem I now have is on the POST side - it is still running hundreds of duplicate queries according to Django Debug Toolbar when the form is submitted.  I have spent hours reading through formset documentation and suggestions on various blogs and here.  The last thing I tried was to set the formset queryset to a custom query and with select_related() for each ForeignKey field.  This does appear to make the main query include alot of joins according to DjDT but it does not eliminate the remaining hundreds of queries on POST.  I've already pulled all my hair out, so maybe someone has a suggestion or can see what I've done wrong?

My models:

```
class Info(AbstractAddArchive):
    item= models.ForeignKey(ITEM, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    rec= models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    c1 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    c1rec = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='c1rec', blank=True, null=True)
    c1sts = models.ForeignKey(Sts, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    c1f = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c2 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    c2rec = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='c2rec', blank=True, null=True)
    c2sts = models.ForeignKey(Sts, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, related_name='c2sts')
    c2f = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c3 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    c3rec = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='c3rec', blank=True, null=True)
    c3sts = models.ForeignKey(Sts, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, related_name='c3sts')
    c3f = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    c4 = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    c4rec = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='c4rec', blank=True, null=True)
    c4sts = models.ForeignKey(Sts, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, related_name='c4sts')
    c4 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment1 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    comment2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    posted_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('item',)  # This sets initial order of formset display

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item_id}"

class Log(AbstractAddArchive):
    rec= models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    ... other fields ...
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.name}"

class Sts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    sequence = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

My Form and formset:

```
class InfoReviseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = ('rec',
                  'c1rec',
                  'c1f',
                  'c1sts',
                  'c2rec',
                  'c2f',
                  'c2sts',
                  'c3rec',
                  'c3f',
                  'c3sts',
                  'c4rec',
                  'c4f',
                  'c4sts',
                  'comment1',
                  )
        widgets = {
            'rec': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'autocomplete',       
                'placeholder': 'Choose rec...',
                'app': 'appname',
                'model-class': 'Log',
                'search-field': 'rec',
                'autocomplete-url': reverse_lazy('autocomplete_field')}),
            ... similar for all foreignkey fields - .js enables autocomplete on each
            }


class InfoBaseFormSet(forms.BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Info.objects.select_related('rec').select_related('c1rec').select_related('c2rec').select_related('c3rec').select_related('c4rec').select_related('car').select_related('c1sts').select_related('c2sts').select_related('c3sts').select_related('c4sts')

InfoReviseFormset = modelformset_factory(Info, form=InfoReviseForm, extra=0, formset=InfoBaseFormSet)
```

My view (post method)

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = InfoReviseFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                if form.has_changed():
                    carinfo_active = form.instance
                    carinfo_active.posted_by = request.user
                    carinfo_active.save()  #save new data - updates existing non archive record
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

From what I can tell, "if formset.is_valid" is where alot of those queries run - but it is also slow after that as well.  BTW, currently I have about 55 forms in the formset - the max number of forms could be as high as 200 which will only slow things down more.  If I can cut down on the queries, I think this will run more reasonably.

I simplified some of the code above - if anything is missing to help take a look, I am happy to post more.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Saving each object individually in a loop is a thing that might be very slow. You could just do the validation there, put the validated objects in a list and save that list in bulk, when you're done with validating all the objects. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-bulk-methods

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The loop checks if the form has changed before saving - all the hundreds of SQL queries run even if only 1 form in the formset has changed - so the proliferation of SQL queries is happening elsewhere...

Comment: How about you override the is_valid-method and make sure it doesn't query the database once per form, but once per formset. You'd probably have to override is_valid on the formclass as well, and add the possibility to give it the querysets to use per parameter, so you can use QuerySets that were previously evaluated. You can force the full evaluation of a queryset with `list(qs)`. Do that at the start of the formset's is_valid.

Comment: Thank you.  On the right track.  It is definitely running many is_valid calls at both the form and formset levels.  Based on when I see the SQL run (in postgresql dashboard) and when the many is_valid methods run, it seems the SQL runs prior to any is_valid after which each is_valid runs quickly, so it seems to be generating all the data to use earlier in the process and then each is_valid has access.  Where in the process is the sql generated, and how would one put a queryset to generate the sql once to be accessed across all is_valid calls?

Comment: Is there a way to use the original queryset that generates the formset to begin with?  That queryset gets all the data necessary in one sql query.

Comment: Probably the `models.ForeignKey`-fields get displayed as `forms.ModelChoiceField`s. By default the widget for these loads a list of all possible choices. In the case of ForeignKey-fields this means each widget causes a database-query. If that is the case, you should be able to fix this by initialising the form-fields with a given list of choices, or by using a different widget like the one used for [autocomplete-fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) in the admin-app

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot that you're already doing that. Did you set the keys for the widgets-dict correctly? The one in your example at least isn't present in fields.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the keys for the widgets-dict

Comment: In your example the `InfoReviseForm.Meta.widgets` begins with the entry with the key `'receiver'`, but there is no `'receiver'` in `InfoReviseForm.Meta.fields`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - it was a typo - I updated the question and changed the widget to 'rec'

Comment: @SMoenig, thanks - it was the issue for me for slow loading of forms.

Comment: Was there a resolution on this?  I'm facing a very similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

The poor performance is likely in the **View** relating to `formset.is_valid()` and related to your queryset.  Try moving the querset definition from the Class Definition of the Form to an explicit callout in the View.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    myquery = Info.objects.select_related('rec').select_related('c1rec').select_related('c2rec').select_related('c3rec').select_related('c4rec').select_related('car').select_related('c1sts').select_related('c2sts').select_related('c3sts').select_related('c4sts')
    formset = InfoReviseFormset(request.POST, queryset=myquery)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            if form.has_changed():
                carinfo_active = form.instance
                carinfo_active.posted_by = request.user
                carinfo_active.save()  #save new data - updates existing non archive record
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In a similar situation I found that my save times became increasingly long as the total number of model instances in the Project grew.  To debug the issue I measured the time at each line of code and isolated the issue to `formset.is_valid()`.  The save times were reduced from 10 seconds per formset to less than half a second by adding an explicit queryset.

Example:

```
assyform = AssyModelFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='assy', queryset=assembly_query)
```

Comment: Hi George. Sorry for the extra question: do you have a specific package or technique to measure the time of each line of code? or you simply printed to the terminal the timestamps in between each line? I am asking in case there is a specific approach that is "the way to go" to track down "the slow line in my code".

Comment: No, I just used `import time` and printed the elapsed time between groups of lines until I narrowed it down to the single line that was causing the delay. In my case most lines were tenths or hundredths of a second whereas the offending line was 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue using formset and use django-debug-toolbar to look at the amount of queries being made.